# unable to play music from document directory through AVPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

I am picking the music file using **MediaPickerController**.After i pick the music file from the picker then i save the file to document directory.

**Following is code for picking & saving to document directory**

```
//code to click on music button
- (IBAction)addMusic:(id)sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *soundPicker=[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    soundPicker.delegate=self;
    soundPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems=NO;
    [self presentViewController:soundPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    NSLog(@"music files delegate called");
    MPMediaItem *item = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self uploadMusicFile:item];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) uploadMusicFile:(MPMediaItem *)song
{
    NSURL *url = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    exporter.outputFileType =   @"com.apple.m4a-audio";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * myDocumentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *intervalSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",seconds];

    NSString * fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",intervalSeconds];

    NSString *exportFile = [myDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile];
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL;

    // do the export
    // (completion handler block omitted)
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^{
         int exportStatus = exporter.status;

         switch (exportStatus)
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             {
                 NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);
                 break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                 //music data is NSdata
                 music_data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [myDocumentsDirectory
                                                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];

                 // NSLog(@"Data %@",data);
                 // data = nil;

                 break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown"); break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting"); break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled"); break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting"); break;
             }
             default:
             {
                 NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

**Code to play the music file from document directory**

```
- (void)musicPlay:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(!isMusicPlaying)
    {
        if([musicFile isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            NSLog(@"INSIDE IF");

            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"No music exist" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            NSURL *fileURL;
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            bc.music_upload=[bc.music_upload lastPathComponent];
            NSLog(@"music uplaod is %@",bc.music_upload);
            NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:bc.music_upload];
            BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
            if(fileExists)
            {
                NSLog(@"file already exist");
                fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
                NSLog(@"file url is %@",fileURL);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"file already not exist");
                if(![musicFile containsString:@"http://"])
                {
                    musicFile=[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:musicFile];

                }
                fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:musicFile]];
            }

            NSLog(@"file url is %@",fileURL);
            isMusicPlaying=true;
            [self.img_music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_stop.png"]];
            playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:fileURL];
            player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
            //player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:path];
            [player play];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isMusicPlaying=false;
        [player pause];
        [self.img_music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music-icon.png"]];
    }
}
```

I am able to save the file & when i check if file exists in document directory then i am able to find the file.But i am not able to play the file.I didn't understand what is the problem.Is problem with the music file or with my music player code?
'
**EDIT:**
I have tried this code but it is making app hang & unresponsive.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sound18.mp3pk.com/pop_remix/ebodf11/ebodf11-15(www.songs.pk).mp3"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];

[audioPlayer play];
```

**EDIT:**

I think the issue is with the conversion of the **MPMediaItem** into **NSdata**.Because when i convert the **MPMediaItem** to **NSData** then i am able to send it server & it is played on the browser.But i try to play with **AVPlayer** then i face this issue?

Answer (score 3):

From [Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)

> As with assets and items, initializing the player does not mean it’s ready for playback. You should observe the player’s status property, which changes to AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay when it is ready to play. You can also observe the currentItem property to access the player item created for the stream.

Add the observer to your player

```
- (void)musicPlay:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // your player code
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}

// Observe for the player status
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {


    if (object == _player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
            [_player play];


        } else if (_player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath]; // like file:///...
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
if (asset) {
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: it is not working.I am uploading file to server by converting it to NSData.

Comment: when i pick the item i convert to it to nsdata see my code.Then i upload it to server.When i give url of music file then it is fine.But when i play same url in my app then it does not play.But if i give any other url in my app then i am able to play music .Please tell me why it is happening

Comment: url link does not help.I have tried the code.but still the same problem @Danilo

Answer (score 0):

Could you please ensure that you are importing `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`.

Also, with ARC, you got to hold a strong reference to `AVPlayer` object. Please try by declaring one strong property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
```

Comment: I am importing these: **#import <AVFoundation/AVPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVPlayerItem.h>** @Abhinav

Comment: I see. Can you please try with strong reference to 'AVPlayer'

Comment: see i am able to play the file on browser & also if i give some third party url then i am able to play the file.but the file which i am uploading is not working fine.@Abhinav